# Internet speed slow on one OS but not another

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection, macbook-pro

I use Mac, various Linuxes, and Windows all on the same MacBook, and for some reason, the internet speed (namely download speed) becomes horrendous when I'm using Windows 10 on my MacBook. What's more bizarre is that when I am ever downloading something on the Windows 10 on my MacBook, internet speeds for any other device also becomes unbearably slow on the same band (e.g. using 2.4 GHz would slow that band to a crawl for every other device, but 5 GHz would be fine, or vice versa), even though I don't notice any abnormally high network utilisation. To ensure that it isn't a service or ISP issue, I've tested my internet speed at different times over the course of a week, with and without my anomalous Win10 MacBook connected to the network, connecting to the same or a different band. Terrible internet speed always coincided with the Win10 MacBook doing absolutely anything that involves doing things over the net on the same band.

My current guess is that there is something wrong with the network driver (this anomaly does not occur when running macOS). However, I'm pretty sure I had installed the correct drivers for it using the drivers that came with Boot Camp's Windows Support software, though I could be wrong.

**Edit 0:** My usual download speed is around 28 to 35 Mbps, but slows to 0 to 1.5 Mbps during this anomaly. My Win10 MacBook would be the least slow, and other devices would often be crippled, sometimes with a download speed of 0.

**Edit 1:** As for network devices, I've got a **Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter**, a **NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller**, and a bunch of **WAN Miniports**.

Comment: Try disabling all network devices, and try turning them on one by one at a time. Are you connected to one network using both (or all) network devices?

Comment: I reinstalled the drivers just now, and it's still just as slow. I only ever connect to one network at a time, one network device at a time. Speaking of which, this anomaly also doesn't happen when using a USB network adapter, so it really is looking like a driver issue. I don't really see how it could starve other computers of internet speed, though.

Comment: It might also be a router issue, but I haven't another access point on which to test yet.